# If/Else Statement in Python ArcGIS Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table, python-parser, if-else

I have a shapefile and want to calculate a field based on another field. The two fields are "DURATION" and "STATUS". I need "STATUS" to display three different outputs based on "DURATION". I want "STATUS" to display a "1" if "DURATION" is greater than 31. I want "STATUS" to display a "2" if "DURATION" is less than or equal to 31 but greater than 0. I need "STATUS" to display "3" if "DURATION" less than or equal to 0.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, for coding question please provide your best code attempt in your question and let us know where you are stuck.  This forum discourages on do it for me questions.